# Extract objects with specific date from custom object Array

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdate, nspredicate

I have an ordered array of Availability object which is a class containing two attributes, startAt and endAt.

I'd like to extract from my availability array the objects from a specific day without taking into account the time.

I'd also like to use NSPredicate instead of "for" loop to do it.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: what did you try? what went wrong? this isn't a 'please code for me' service

Answer (score 0):

`for-in` loop actually faster than `NSPredicate` for me, and easier since u can convert it to string or extract it for easy compare, but if u want then the format should be:

`@"(%@ >= %@) AND (%@ <= %@)", dateForCompare, dayStart, dateForCompare, dayEnd` where `dayStart` is the date to compare at `00:00:00`, `dayEnd` is the date to compare at `23:59:59`, tweak it base on your needs, u have to do this because a `NSDate` object contain exact date and time

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

if you are using timestamp(NSNumber) to store startAt and endAt then you can use predicate as bellow (to fetch all object whose start date is greter then current date)

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startAt > %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]];
NSArray *filteredArr = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

and if you are using only date string then you can use

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startAt = %@", @"your date string must be same as formate you saved in array"];
```

and if you are using only date string then you can use